# Laravel queue not doing Jobs with DB driver

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-queue

I have a problem, I have a job that when I dispatch on database driver it sais Processed, but it does not work, it should upload a file with Curl.
If I do it with driver sync it works. Since there are no errors, I don't know how to figure it out with the DB driver.
It's a test new project, I thought it may be from other code, but it looks like not.
This is the code from routes web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
class UploadFile implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $filename, $url;

    public function __construct($filename, $url)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->url = $url;        }

    public function upload(){
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('did' => 0,'file[]'=> new \CURLFILE($this->filename)),
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . env('API_KEY')
        ),
      ));

        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->upload();
    }
}

class Upload
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->getServer();
    }
    function getServer(){
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->get("https://api.website.com/v1/upload/get_server.cgi" ,[
            'headers' => [
                "Content-Type" => "application/json",
            ]
        ]);
        $response = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        $this->url = $response->url . '/upload.cgi?id=' . $response->id;
    }

    public function uploadFile(Request $request){

      // Validation
      $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:zip,png,jpg,jpeg,csv,txt,pdf'
    ]); 

      if($request->file('file')) {
         $file = $request->file('file');
         $filename = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

         $file->move(base_path('public'),$filename);

         Session::flash('message','Upload Successfully.');
         Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-success');

         UploadFile::dispatch($filename, $this->url);
     }else{
         Session::flash('message','File not uploaded.');
         Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
     }
     return redirect()->route('home');
 }


}



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->name('home');
Route::post('/uploadFile', [Upload::class, 'uploadFile'])->name('uploadFile');
```

Comment: This env('API_KEY') seems incorrect, can you do something like this config('app.API_KEY') and check. Before this, you have to add API_KEY in config/app.php file like this 'API_KEY' => env('API_KEY');

Answer (score 0):

When you set the database as a queue driver you have to run this command in the terminal.

```
php artisan queue:work
```

Alternatively, you can also run this command

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

But the former is more efficient than the latter.

You can get more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#the-queue-work-command).

Comment: Already tried with both, as I said, there it sais Jobs are beeing processed, not going to failed queue

Comment: Sorry, I am having a problem understanding you. What do you mean by not going to failed queue? If you have set QUEUE_DRIVER=database in .env file. Then you must run 

php artisan queue:table

php artisan migrate

so that all job and failed_jobs tables will be created in your database.

Comment: The jobs are beeing processed as Success, but the CURL part with the fileupload does not work, and when set to SYNC it works, the file gets uploaded to that server.

Comment: There may be two problems, one: the queue uses php-cli, can you check is cURL enabled in php-cli?  or it might be possible that cURL takes more time in processing the request that's why your file is not getting uploaded you can run this command then php artisan queue:listen --timeout=60.